# why do I get the error: pygame.error: video system not initialized

Tags: python, pygame

Like the title says I am confused why I get the error: pygame.error: video system not initialized

As far as i understand this error is raised if you forget to initialize your code with pygame.init() but I did, here's my code and thanks in advance:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen_height = 700
screen_width = 1000

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("platformer")

# load images
sun_img = pygame.image.load("img/sun.png")
backround_img = pygame.image.load("img/sky.png")


run = True
while run:

    screen.blit (backround_img,(0,0))
    screen.blit(sun_img, (100, 50))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()

    pygame.display.update()
```

the error does not crash the window or anything and it works as intended
its just somewhat annoying.

Comment: iam on macOS and iam using Pycharm

Comment: i kinda fixed it now. Instead of using run = False and pygame.quit to quit the window iam now using sys.exit and for some reason it doesn't raise the error anymore. I have no idea why though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()

    pygame.display.update()
```

When the event loop happens, if you close the window, you call pygame.quit(), which quits pygame.  Then it tries to do:

```
pygame.display.update()
```

But pygame has quit, which is why you are getting the message.

separate the logic out.  Events in one function or method, updating in another, and drawing and updating the display in another to avoid this.